# angularjs nested directive scope isolation hiding parent directive object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create nested directive that ordered **top**, **parent** and **sub**.

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <top>
    <parent>
        <sub global-name="global"></sub>
    </parent>
  </top>
</div>
```

And my jsvascript is:

```
angular.module("app",[]);

angular.module("app").directive("top",function(){
    return {
                restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div ng-transclude></div>"
    }
});

angular.module("app").directive("parent", function(){
        return {
            restrict: "E",
        controller: function($scope){
                $scope.global = {
                    name: "parent directive"
            };
        },
        link: function(scope){

        },
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div ng-transclude></div>"
    }
});

angular.module("app").directive("sub", function(){
        return {
            restrict: "E",
        require:"^parent",
        scope: {
                global: "=globalName"
        },
        controller: function(){

        },
        link: function(scope){
                scope.title = scope.global;
            console.log(scope.global);
        },
        template: "{{global.name}}"
    }
});
```

this is working. [JSfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/mLb5bhbm/5/) is here. But;

if I isolate **parent** directive scope, I can not access the `global` object of **parent** from sub directive.

```
angular.module("app").directive("parent", function(){
        return {
            restrict: "E",
        controller: function($scope){
                $scope.global = {
                    name: "parent directive"
            };
        },
        link: function(scope){

        },
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div ng-transclude></div>",
        scope: {}
    }
});
```

This is not working. [Jsfiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/mLb5bhbm/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't, that's all the point of isolted scopes, since both your parent and sub directive have isolate scopes this doesn't work.

When you want to have 2 directive having a parent/child relationship, you use the parent's controller API to communicate with from the sub directive to the parent.

Check this Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/tp1pc31z/

```
angular.module("app").directive("parent", function(){
        return {
            restrict: "E",
        controller: function($scope){
                this.global = {name:"parent directive"};
        },
        link: function(scope){

        },
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div ng-transclude></div>",
        scope: {}
    }
});

angular.module("app").directive("sub", function(){
        return {
            restrict: "E",
        require:"^parent",
        scope:{},
        controller: function(){

        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr, parentCtrl){
            console.log("parent : "+parentCtrl);
                scope.title = parentCtrl.global;
            console.log(scope.title.name);
        },
        template: "Global : {{title.name}}"
    }
})
```

Comment: If I pass parent object to sub, I have two way. I will not set isolate scope of parent. or if I isolate scope of parent, I should use require in sub directive to access parent controller.

Comment: this is exactly what i have done, i access to parent controller instead of scope, that how you do it with ng-model and that how angular-messages works. Using scopes between directives is just a really bad idea IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a different approach - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/camden_kid/0Lyb5xa9/10/)

JS

```
angular.module("app",[]);

angular.module("app").directive("top",function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<parent></parent>"
    }
});

angular.module("app").directive("parent", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.global = {
                name: "parent directive"
            };
        },
        link: function(scope){

        },
        template: "<sub global='global'></sub>",
        scope: {}
    }
});

angular.module("app").directive("sub", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            global: "="
        },
        controller: function(){

        },
        link: function(scope){
            scope.title = scope.global;
            console.log(scope.global);
        },
        template: "{{global.name}}"
    }
});
```

Markup

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <top>
  </top>
</div>
```